# Spark head() takes too long time for a dataset with a single row

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm using `head()` function to get the first row (which is the only row) after aggregation in a dataset, as follows:

```
numeratorDataset = vector0.join(vector1, "wikibase_item").map(new MapFunction<Row, TFIDFComponent>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public TFIDFComponent call(Row row) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new TFIDFComponent(row.getString(0), row.getDouble(1)*row.getDouble(2));
    }
}, Encoders.bean(TFIDFComponent.class));

numerator = numeratorDataset.agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum(numeratorDataset.col("weight"))).head().getDouble(0);
```

I found it takes too much time although it is a single row. Any idea why? how can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you provide the code that you have written for creating `numeratorDataset`?

Comment: How big is your Input? i.e source of nymeratorDataset? If this is large then aggregate functions will take time to give the results.

Comment: @himanshuIIITian, I just updated my question to include the numeratorDataset.

Comment: @Ganesh ,actually from the Spark UI, the head function takes the long time, not the aggregation.

Comment: operations you are doing before the head API are lazy, which gets executed once you call head. So it's taking time.

Comment: It's a real paint to me..any thought to improve these operations?

Comment: One solution I would think of is keep the results in cache beforehand and just fetch the value from cache when the call happens from UI.